# Is it correct and natural to say "catch up with someone on something"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *catch up with someone on something*? For example:

> Today I'm going to **catch up with you on** *Friends*.

What I'm trying to say is that I'm going to watch as many episodes as the person I was talking to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sense it's fine - you're saying you want to *catch up with someone* (i.e. you're behind them and want to reach their position).

You could also say *catch up **to** you* and that might actually be a better choice, because *catch up with you* can also mean "have a conversation with you where we talk about all the things we haven't discussed yet", like when you haven't seen someone for a while, and there are things you want to *catch up* on. *Catch up with you on Friends* could be understood as "talk to you on the subject of Friends", which isn't really what you want to say!

Personally I think *catch up to you **with** Friends* feels the most natural and clear, and *with* just generally works. *On* can sometimes sound a little strange and might need a verb, like *catch up to you **on watching Friends***. It's very subtle and I'm having trouble pinning down exactly what I don't like about *on* to be honest, it's definitely the right word in some ways! *With* is definitely safer.

edit - I know, it's because *catch up on Friends* is what you'd say when there's something you want to make progress with, where you want to get up to date with the show. But adding *with you* or *to you* makes it sound a little awkward, for some reason. English!